# css styles are not getting applied in modal dialog - how can I fix?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react, react-sortable-hoc

React 16.13.1; Semantic UI React 2.0.2

Happens on Chrome, Firefox and Edge

I'm using `SortableContainer` from `react-sortable-hoc` package to make a UI for sorting an array. I'm having trouble with the css styling under the context that I'd like to use the package in. In a different context, it's behaving how I'd like.

Here's the context in which it's working. See notes below each image.

[image]
In the above image, the sortable list is in the lower left. This shows its idle state for context.

[image]
In the above image, note that the list item that's being dragged has a yellow border and the text is visible. The `SortableList` element creates a new element on-demand that gets dragged around. The styling is set by a class that's passed to the `SortableList` element. In this case, the class is called `file-upload-sortable-list-item-helper`, as seen in the Elements pane by the red arrow.

But I need the sortable list in its own modal window rather than in the table cell as shown above. But when I do that, the styling doesn't get set for the item as it's dragged. But first, here's the sortable list in a modal window at idle.

[image]
In the above picture, the sortable list is in a modal window and is at idle. So far so good.

[image]
In the above picture, the item that's being dragged is not styled properly, and is practically invisible (red arrow 1), even though the Elements pane is showing that the `file-upload-sortable-list-item-helper` is set for the item (red arrow 2).

I can't figure out how to get the Chrome dev tools to show me the item Style details for the dragged item, because if I enter element selection mode and click on the list item, it doesn't get activated for dragging. I have to then click again to start it dragging but by then the element selection mode is deactivated.

Here's the relevant style definitions

```
.file-upload-sortable-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
.file-upload-sortable-list-item {
    /*border-style: solid;*/
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    border-color: rgb(84,200,255);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
/* This class is for the list item that moves
around when using the SortableList. Because
of how it's instantiated on-demand, it can't be
a child of .pennai.
The most important part is the z-index. Without it
the element isn't visible at all.
See https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/issues/87
*/
.file-upload-sortable-list-item-helper {
    border: 2px solid;
    text-align: center;
    /* something happens to the padding compared to the regular item defined above,
       and the text is aligned at bottom of border instead of middle.
       But these settings aren't effecting things. Huh. 
    */
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    border-color: yellow; /* rgb(84,200,255);*/
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 10; /*important*/
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    list-style-type: none; /*remove the bullet*/
 }
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

UPDATE:
I've figured out how to get the dev tools to show me computed styles for the dragged list item: give keyboard focus to the element hierarchy pane; click and start dragging a list item and hold mouse button down; hit ctrl-shift-c to enter element-selection mode; use arrow keys to change the highlighted element in the hierarchy pane to put focus on the newly-created list item that shows the dragging. Then the styles pane on the right shows styles for the special list item that's being dragged. Phew!

If you look at the screenshot below, you can see that the styles I'm applying for the dragged item (arrow 1) are actually showing up properly, but not all of them are being rendered properly. For example the border color and text color (arrows 2) are NOT being rendered, but the border radius (arrow 3) and `list-style-type` (disc) ARE being rendered properly (but it's hard to see here with the dev tools element-selection highlight applied.

Does anyone have any idea why this may be? Thanks

UPDATE 2: If I enable the '.cls' option in the dev tools' Styles panel as suggested in the comments here, and then add the `.file-upload-sortable-list-item-helper` class, the list item is rendered properly! But still not rendered properly when actually clicking and dragging an item.

[image]

Comment: There's a :hov option in the CSS menu in developer menu; when you select an element and use that it gives you some nice debugging options for stylizing CSS like that, in different states. There's the .CLS for classes too, if you wanted to check quickly .red .blue .green type stuff. :)

Comment: Thanks @blanknamefornow - the `:hov` options didn't help, but the `.cls` option is very cool. Interestingly, when I add it to a list item, it shows correctly! But when I undo that and start dragging the item normally, not all of the style properties are rendered - see my updated question above.

Comment: I've given up on this for now because I found a workaround for what I needed to do - I haven't fixed the problem itself. Instead of trying to use `SortableList` in a Semantic UI Modal component, I'm just using it in a pseudo-modal implementation by rendering only a top-level div with SortableList and some for the rest of the UI to use the list.